# disabled automatic use of client certificate & curl: (60) schannel: CertGetCertificateChain trust error CERT_TRUST_IS_UNTRUSTED_ROOT

Tags: ssl, curl, jenkins-pipeline

sh """echo quit | openssl s_client -showcerts  -servername **.**.**.*** -connect **.**.**.***:443 > cacert.pem"""

*def response = sh """curl --cacert cacert.pem -v -d '{....}' -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST url"""*

**above curl command i used to execute but got below error**

schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate

- ALPN: offers http/1.1

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* schannel: added 2 certificate(s) from CA file 'cacert.pem'
- schannel: CertGetCertificateChain trust error CERT_TRUST_IS_UNTRUSTED_ROOT

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (60) schannel: CertGetCertificateChain trust error CERT_TRUST_IS_UNTRUSTED_ROOT